# Calling function in kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, kivy, object-recognition

The code below is for object detection. I build the code and worked fine, but when I pasted the code in kivy python I got errors.

I got a error in calling a function which is outside of the kivy class. So, please help me to reslove the error.

And tell me how can I call the function to run the code.

CODE FOLLOWS:

```
from __future__ import division
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from math import cos, sin 

green = (0, 255, 0)

class face(App):

def show(self, image):
    #figure size in inches
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')

def overlay_mask(self, mask, image):
    #mask the mask rgb
    rgb_mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

    img = cv2.addWeighted(rgb_mask, 0.5, image, 0.5, 0)
    return img

def find_biggest_contour(self, image):
    #copy image
    image = image.copy()
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #to find biggest contour
    contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
    biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]

    #return the biggest contour
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [biggest_contour], -1, 255, -1)
    return biggest_contour, mask

def circle_contour(self, image, contour):

    #bounding ellipse
    image_with_ellipse = image.copy()
    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
    #add it
    cv2.ellipse(image_with_ellipse, ellipse, green, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    return image_with_ellipse

def find_object(self, image):
    #RGB is red green blue
    #BGR is blue green red
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    #to scale the image
    max_dimension = max(image.shape)
    scale = 700/max_dimension
    image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

    #to clean the image 
    image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (7,7), 0)
    image_blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_blur, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

    #defining the filters by color
    min_red = np.array([0,100, 80])
    max_red = np.array([10,256, 256])

    mask1 = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_red, max_red)

    #filter by brightness
    min_red2 = np.array([170,100,80])
    max_red2 = np.array([100,256,256])

    mask2 = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_red2, max_red2)

    mask = mask1 + mask2

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
    mask_closed = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    mask_clean = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_closed, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    big_object_contour, mask_object = find_biggest_contour(mask_clean)

    overlay = overlay_mask(mask_clean, image)

    circled = circle_contour(overlay, big_object_contour)
    show(circled)

    #convert back to original color scheme
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(circled, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return bgr
    
#to read the image
def call(self):
    image = cv2.imread('apple.jpeg')
    result = self.find_object(image)
    #write the new image
    cv2.imwrite('apple2.jpeg', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   face().run()
   #img = Image(source = "apple2.jpeg")
   #print(img)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can call function from a class

class A:

```
    def __init__(self):
         pass
    def x(self):
        print('x')
```

class B:

```
    def __init__(self):
        A().x()
```